# How to build a custom logic app for Form recognizer 3.0?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-form-recognizer, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm currently trying to make an automation tool with Form recognizer and Logic app.
Since the last Build, Microsoft introduced the multi page table analysis for custom model with the 3.O api.

I spend a lot of time trying to call a model and start an analysis with many logic app but figured it out that it's actually impossible to call a model trained with the 3.0 api (new form recognizer studio).

My only solution is to create a custom Logic app to use the multi page analysis new feature with the 3.0 api.

I didn't find any ressource who explain how to do it. Any tips?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, the Form Recognizer Logic App connector currently supports the 2.1 API and does not yet support the 3.0 API. To call a 3.0 API model from logic app you will need to create a custom connector. You can use the Form Recognizer REST API  for the custom connector - https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2022-06-30-preview/operations/AnalyzeDocument